# File from wget in script not available for next command

Tags: wget

I am wget-ing a file and to preserve its original file name i do a `find` for its known extension.

Everything is working fine on the terminal but in a script the file is never available/there for the find command.

I guess after wget completes the download the file is not yet persisted to the file system ...

How can I wait for the file to be available?

```
wget -q -N "$BASEURL/$VERSION"
echo $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.jar)
```

Comment: First, I'd use the `-O` option to specify a file path/name to output to - this way, you skip the find step.  If the file really isn't there until `wget` has finally finished, then adding a `sleep 3` (or however many seconds you want) after the `wget` and before your next command(s) should do it.  Be sure to quote the url you are `wget`-ing in case it has ampersands, etc. in it (which would send `wget` to the background and let the script continue, which means the file wouldn't be totally there)

Comment: sleep is working but very ugly, I don't want -O because I want to preserve its original name and the files are behind redirects

Comment: Can you please paste the script which you tried so far?

Comment: @Thushi updated q

Comment: `#!/bin/sh
wget -q -N google.com
echo $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.html)` This works for me! Can you please paste the error text which you are getting?